# Replace multiple parts of column names at once

Tags: r, string, replace

I have lots of columns with very long names and I want to shorten them by replacing the end part with a blank space.

My data is called "data_names"

I can achieve this with lots of lines of code:

```
site <- stri_replace_all_fixed(data_names, pattern = ".CO.1h.average..ppm.", "")
site <- stri_replace_all_fixed(site, pattern = ".HUMID.1h.average....", "")
site <- stri_replace_all_fixed(site, pattern = ".NEPH.1h.average..bsp.", "")
```

etc...

but I want to be able to do this in one or two lines... can anyone help me? :)

(trying out gsub, do.call, etc)

Comment: Please provide a minimal example with data so that we can help you.

Comment: It would be easier to answer the question if you include the complete column name of at least two column, and provide the desired column name

Comment: You can have multiple patterns as input to `gsub` seperated by `|` for an `OR` condition with `site <- gsub("[.CO.1h.average..ppm.] | [.HUMID.1h.average....] | [.NEPH.1h.average..bsp.]","",data_names)`

Comment: Please show us the full column names (or at least a sample of them). Paste the output of `dput(names(data))` into your question (where `data` should be replaced with the actual name of your data frame). We need to see what regularities exist in the column names in order to create an efficient regular expression that will give the desired output.

Comment: It is not clear about the patterns, but if there are no dots before the first one, then `sub("^([^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", data_names)`